# OR in Common Table Expression - Excessive Recursion

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I am getting the excessive recursion problem with the following and am struggling to visualize where it is going wrong

My data is as follows:

```
Hierarchy       Id      RecNo   ParentRecord   Data
Mike            1       100     
Mike:b1         1       101     100            This One
Mike:b1:c1      1       102     101         
Mike:b1:c1:d    1       103     102
Mike:b1:c2:e    1       104     102
Mike:b2         1       110     100
Dave            2       200     
Dave:b4         2       201     200
Dave:b4:c3      2       202     201
```

I have the following UDFs

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IsParent] ( @HierarchyA VARCHAR(1000), @HierarchyB VARCHAR(1000) )
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ret INT
If dbo.CountChar(@HierarchyA, ':') >= dbo.Ifx_CountChar(@HierarchyB, ':')
    SET @ret = 0
ELSE IF LEFT(@HierarchyB, LEN(@HierarchyA + ':')) = @HierarchyA + ':'
    SET @ret = 1
ELSE
    SET @ret = 0        
RETURN @ret
END

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CountChar] ( @Input VARCHAR(1000), @SearchChar CHAR(1) )
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    RETURN (LEN(@Input) - LEN(REPLACE(@Input, @SearchChar, '')))
END
```

My CTE is as follows:

```
With Trees (Id, Hierachy, RecNo, Tier)
AS
(
    SELECT Id, Hierachy, RecNo, dbo.CountChar(Hierachy, ':') as Tier
    FROM MyData 
    WHERE Data="This One"

UNION ALL   

    SELECT e.Id, e.Hierachy, e.RecNo, dbo.CountChar(e.Hierachy, ':') 
    FROM 
        MyData e 
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT Id, Hierachy, RecNo FROM Trees) s 
    ON e.Id = s.Id
    WHERE dbo.IsParent(s.Hierachy,e.Hierachy) = 1   
    OR dbo.IsParent(e.Hierachy,s.Hierachy) = 1  
)

SELECT * FROM Trees
ORDER BY Hierachy, Tier
```

The cte works fine if I use either of the OR clauses individually but when I use them both it bombs out with the max recursion exceeded error.

I am trying to reconstruct the hierarchy based on a the value of some data. So having found rows with a specific data value, I am wanting to identify all parents and children of that row based on the hierarchical relation specified by the hierarchy field. So in the above instance I am wanting to retrieve the following rows relating to Mike

```
Mike            1       100     
Mike:b1         1       101     100            This One
Mike:b1:c1      1       102     101         
Mike:b1:c1:d    1       103     102
Mike:b1:c2:e    1       104     102
```

I was wondering if someone could

1. explain how to avoid the excessive recursion issue
2. suggest whether using the Hierarchy in this way (using partial string matching) is (or is not) preferable to using the RecNo/ParentRecord relationship to traverse the tree in this instance

Many thx IA

S

Comment: If you can change the schema, using Nested Sets would allow for extremely easy list-all-ancestors-and-descendants queries. If you can't, I'd say 1) two CTEs, one for ancestors one for descendants; 2) SQL 2008 (I think) has an explicit Hierarchy datatype

Comment: @AakashM - thx very much for the speedy response. Unfortunately, I have limited scope to change the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the constraint of not changing the schema, this is what I'd suggest:

- Use two CTEs, one to go up the tree and one to go down
- Within the recursive part of the CTEs, move **just one level** at a time, rather than attempting to check ancestor/descendant status at an arbitrary distance.

Finally I'd note that at present your table has *two* ways of modelling the tree; which should win if they disagree?

Now to the code

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (
    Hierarchy nvarchar(max),
    Id int,
    RecNo int,
    ParentRecord int,
    Data nvarchar(max)
);

INSERT @Data VALUES
('Mike',            1,       100,     NULL,NULL),
('Mike:b1',         1,       101,     100,            'This One'),
('Mike:b1:c1',      1,       102,     101      ,NULL)   ,
('Mike:b1:c1:d',    1,       103,     102,NULL),
('Mike:b1:c2:e',    1,       104,     102,NULL),
('Mike:b2',         1,       110,     100,NULL),
('Dave',            2,       200,     NULL,NULL),
('Dave:b4',         2,       201,     200,NULL),
('Dave:b4:c3',      2,       202,     201,NULL);
```

Query:

```
WITH SelfAndAncestors AS
(
    -- anchor
    SELECT * FROM @Data WHERE Data = 'This One'
    UNION ALL
    -- recursive part
    SELECT Parent.* FROM @Data Parent 
        INNER JOIN SelfAndAncestors Child
        ON Parent.RecNo = Child.ParentRecord
),
SelfAndDescendants AS
(
    -- anchor
    SELECT * FROM @Data WHERE Data = 'This One'
    UNION ALL
    -- recursive part
    SELECT Child.* FROM @Data Child
        INNER JOIN SelfAndDescendants Parent
        ON Parent.RecNo = Child.ParentRecord
)
SELECT * FROM SelfAndAncestors 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM SelfAndDescendants
ORDER BY Hierarchy
```

For convenience, both CTEs include the record of interest (`This One`), and the `UNION` removes the duplicate.

Results:

```
Hierarchy              Id          RecNo       ParentRecord Data
---------------------- ----------- ----------- ------------ ---------------------
Mike                   1           100         NULL         NULL
Mike:b1                1           101         100          This One
Mike:b1:c1             1           102         101          NULL
Mike:b1:c1:d           1           103         102          NULL
Mike:b1:c2:e           1           104         102          NULL
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks very much. I was coming to the view that I'd need upward AND downward traversal, but didn't realise you could do multiple CTEs like that! Very good. (I think the RecNo/ParentRecord is probably the "winning" relationship)

Comment: another quick q ... do you think this is the "right" way to do this rather than returning the salient records and constructing the tree in a business logic tier?

Comment: @SimonWoods yes, even if you're going to be getting objects out at the end, you still need to identify the salient records in the first place, and for that the database is the best place to work it out. Unless of course you already have the whole dataset as objects in memory, but I'm guessing you don't.